# Component for saving a record but relies on its container for its HTML?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I have two components, **form.app** and **newcase.cmp**.

**newcase.cmp**

Component declares an attribute for a new case record. Its controller would save the new case to the server; maybe some client-side validation, and error reporting as well.

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="newCase" type="Case" default="{ 'sobjectType' : 'Case' }" />
</aura:component>
```

**newcaseController.js**

```
({
    save : function (component, event, helper)
    {
        // call @AuraEnabled
    }   
})
```

**form.app**

My hope is for this to implement the look and feel of the form.

```
<aura:application>
    ...
    <c:newcase>
        <div>
            <ui:inputText value="{!v.newCase.SuppliedName}" />
        </div>
        ...
    </c:newcase>
    ...
</aura:application>
```

**form.app** throws as it expects `newCase` to be an attribute of it.

Essentially, my goal is to have a reusable `newcase.cmp` component which contains common logic: validation and saving, and then leave the look and feel of the form to its containers, `form.app` in this case.

How can I achieve my goal?

I've also tried replacing

```
<ui:inputText value="{!v.newCase.SuppliedName}" />
```

with

```
<ui:inputText aura:id="case_name" />
```

Hoping that I could `component.get("v.body")[0].find("case_name")` in the controller of newcase.cmp but that doesn't work. Likely due to scope as well.

Comment: What do you expect from this piece of code `<div> <ui:inputText value="{!v.newCase.SuppliedName}" /> </div>` inside your component `<c:newcase>`?

Comment: I was hoping it would be a part of a `<form>` whose input elements are bound to fields of the `newCase` attribute inside `<c:newcase>` component.

Comment: Your attributes are gonna be part of your component itself, not the container. Try with just `<c:newcase />

Comment: What would be a good design to make sure the there's a reusable code/component/helper for saving a record, but leave the presentation layer to the container? For our use case, we have several forms for creating a case, all of which have varying look and feel.